# How can I know if I have the latest version of ROS packages?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, ubuntu, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Lunar on an Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

I have followed the steps in [Lunar Installation instructions for Ubuntu](http://wiki.ros.org/lunar/Installation/Ubuntu).

How can I know if I have the latest ros packages' version?

I did:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade
```

And it doesn't install anything. Maybe I have to add another repository.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302690/how-can-i-know-if-i-have-the-latest-version-of-ros-packages?/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> And it doesn't install anything.

If `apt-get upgrade` doesn't install anything, then it would appear you have the latest releases of all packages.

> Maybe I have to add another repository.

No, I don't believe so.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3